# Buffer viewer says "failed to load config file" in Tosca Commander

Tags: config, tosca, failed-to-load-viewstate

I'm not able to view buffers in Tricentis Tosca Commander when I try to click on 'Buffer Viewer' it will prompts error: "failed to load config file"

It's an emergency, pls help...

I expected buffers but getting error.